# OAuth2 Callback not hitting handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

When the server I'm authenticating with responds with the redirect back to my callback URL, my code doesn't seem to know how to handle the request - as if I'm missing a handler.

I thought the CallbackPath property would wire this up and pass the incoming request to my handler, is that not correct?

I just get a 404 from my app, the URL has the code=XXXX etc.

Here's my code

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

  string authScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

  services.AddAuthentication(o =>
  {
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "MyAuthScheme";
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

  }).AddOAuth(authScheme, options =>
  {
     options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://example.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://example.net/";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://example.com/adfs/oauth2/token";
    options.CallbackPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/signin-myauthserver");
    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  });


  services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());


}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  }

  app.UseAuthentication();

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I feel like what you want is Open Id Connect, not OAuth.

Comment: I can't as this is hitting ADFS on Windows server 2012, and AFAIK that doesn't support oidc

Comment: same problem here, I was trying to implement a wechat login for .net core 5 API.